# suspicious cast there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

I should cast one class into Generic Interface because of some requirements. But I am having ReSharper warning "suspicious cast there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both". In run time, it cause run time error.

I should do this because I am using reflection so I desperetly need this cast.
My code as below. Any support appreceated.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // prepare class name from string
        string propertyNavigationFullName = "ConsoleApp1.Entry";

        // Take assembly
        Assembly assem = typeof(Entry).Assembly;

        // take class type
        Type className = assem.GetType(propertyNavigationFullName, true);

        // create class instance
        IEntitySubMultiLang inst = (IEntitySubMultiLang)Activator.CreateInstance(className);

        // prepare Generic Class
        Type genericClass = typeof(GenericRepo<>);
        Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(className);

        // create Generic Class instance
        // ERROR OCCUR HERE
        IRepo<IEntitySubMultiLang> created = (IRepo<IEntitySubMultiLang>)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);

        // I need to use Add method or any other method
        created.Add(inst);

    }

    public interface IEntitySubMultiLang
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepo<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntitySubMultiLang
    {
        void Add(TEntity item);
    }

    public class GenericRepo<TEntity> : IRepo<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntitySubMultiLang
    {
        public void Add(TEntity item)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Entry : IEntitySubMultiLang
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[ScreenShot](http://mezzanine74-001-site4.htempurl.com/Content/Images/error.png)

Comment: My answer explains why what you're asking doesn't make sense. Can you explain why you "desperately need this cast"? What specifically are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have revised my code above to make more sense, because I need this for reflection. I should have a contract for this class so that I can use .Add(TEntity item) method for any class who implements IEntitySubMultiLang. Whole scenario is little bit complex than this but this is basic need.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about what this means, the cast you're talking about is actually incorrect, which is why it doesn't work. Suppose you have another class that implements IEntitySubMultiLang:

```
public class Foo : IEntitySubMultiLang
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

What would happen if you passed a `Foo` to `_r.Add()`?

```
_r.Add(new Foo());
```

This wouldn't make any sense, because `_r` is a `GenericRepo<Entry>`, and doesn't know how to add `Foo`s. That's exactly the sort of situation type safety is supposed to avoid.

#### Update, based on OP Edit

Because you're using reflection to produce your objects, you're really getting no compile-time benefit from the interfaces in terms of type safety when you're calling `_r.Add()`. So embrace that fact, and use reflection to call the `Add` method, without attempting to do any casting.

```
    constructedClass
        .GetMethod("Add")
        .MakeGenericMethod(className)
        .Invoke(created, new object[] { inst });
```

Alternatively, there is a good chance you can simplify a lot of your code, and still get a lot of type safety, by putting everything into a generic helper method, and calling *that method* by reflection. For example:

```
static private void AddToRepo<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntitySubMultiLang, new
{
    new GenericRepo<TEntity>().Add(new TEntity());
}
```

```
    typeof(ConsoleApp1)
        .GetMethod("AddToRepo")
        .MakeGenericMethod(className)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { /* any parameters? */});
```

Comment: Hello, I revised your first suggestion because it caused a parameter error so it worked in this way. MethodInfo getAllMethod = constructedClass.GetMethod("Add", new Type[] { className }); getAllMethod.Invoke(created, new object[] { inst });

Comment: I will study your second helper suggestion to figure it out. Thank you for support. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use it as an entity, then make it so entities must be derived from the base type:

```
public class GenericRepo<TEntity> : IRepo<TEntity> where TEntity : Entry
```